# How to use testharness for flink timer with 3 inputs

Tags: kotlin, timer, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I wanted to test the flink timers using testHarness, I can do it when I have one input key using `KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness`.
But I wanted to test the process function with 3 input key.

Example:

```
class Sample: KeyedProcessFunction<String, Tuple4<String, input1?, input2?, input3?>, Tuple2<String, sampleOutput?>>
```

I am unable to use the `testHarness` for process function with more than 2 input keys?

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what the problem is you are trying to solve, and what you've already tried? Do you want to test with events from a keyed stream where various events have different values for the key? Or are you wishing for a variant of the test harness that could be used to test an operator with more than 2 input channels? Or something else?

Comment: Never mind, my bad. Did the union of three inputs and used KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness() and it worked.